# Loops in Mustache-Mode Underscore Templates

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

I've set underscore to mustache mode like so:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

I've got part of a template with the following:

```
<script id="detail_view" type="text/template">
    <% for(registration in REGISTRATION_NUMBERS){ %>
        <tr>
            <td>{{registration.TYPE}}</td>
            <td>{{registration.VALUE}}</td>
        </tr>
<% } %>
</script>
```

Which results in "registration not defined". Using `this` causes the entire section to be output in the template. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems, one you know about and one that you don't.

The first problem is that you're replacing all three `_.templateSettings` when you only want to replace one of them. You want this:

```
_.templateSettings.interpolate = /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g;
```

That will leave the `evaluate` and `escape` parts of [`_.templateSettings`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) alone. What you're doing is the same as:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
  evaluate    : undefined,
  escape      : undefined
};
```

so you're ending up without an `evaluate` at all. BTW, you can look at the `source` property of a compiled template function to see the JavaScript that your template is compiled to, the JavaScript isn't that easy on the eyes but looking at it can help with this sort of problem.

The problem you don't know about is that a `for...in` loop is for iterating over the properties of an object, not the values in an array. This means that `registration` will be the strings `'0'`, `'1'`, ... inside your loop and that's not what you want. You'd need something like this in your template if `REGISTRATION_NUMBERS` is an array:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < REGISTRATION_NUMBERS.length; ++i) { %>
    <% var registration = REGISTRATION_NUMBERS[i]; %>
    <tr>
        <td>{{registration.TYPE}}</td>
        <td>{{registration.VALUE}}</td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

Or, since you have Underscore around anyway, you could use [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each):

```
<% _(REGISTRATION_NUMBERS).each(function(r) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>{{r.TYPE}}</td>
        <td>{{r.VALUE}}</td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jfckA/

Comment: the for loop is best for an array, the _().each is only for collections?

Comment: @NicholasMurray: That form of `_.each` is for an array, you'd want `_(obj).each(function(value, key) { ... })` for a non-array object, note the argument order on the callback function. I find `_.each` less noisy than a `for(;;)` loop in a template.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that, that sound you just heard was me converting for loops to _.each, thanks